# Is there any way to intercept javascript triggered URL in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Is there any way to intercept javascript triggered URL in a `WebView` just like normal hrefs using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`onLoadResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) is called when any resource is being called, including JavaScript.  The purpose is a bit different though than [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
webControls.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    //Notify the host application that the WebView will load 
    //the resource specified by the given url.
    @Override  
    public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        Log.v(TAG, "onLoadResource("+url+");");
    }

    //Give the host application a chance to take over the 
    //control when a new url is about to be loaded in the 
    //current WebView. 
    @Override  
    public void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        Log.v(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading("+url+");");
    }
}
```